# Can I use metaprogramming to dynamically initialize a class?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have a script that creates a table like this:

```
class TableClass < Table  
    members :hello, :hallo, :halo  
end
```

This script creates a table with columns labeled "hello", "hallo", and "halo".  I would like to dynamically declare the "members" portion so that I could use results generated by a different script to initialize this table.  I am pretty new to Ruby and extremely new to the concept of metaprogramming, but I feel like this must be doable, I just don't know how yet.

After declaring:

```
ListOfMembers= [:hello, :hallo, :halo]
```

I have tried:

```
members ::ListOfMembers
```

and

```
members eval ::ListOfMembers.join(",")
```

to no avail, and I am unsure of what to search for to figure this out.  All of the metaprogramming examples I have found revolve around class methods and don't seem relevant to this problem.

Scrapping this class structure would probably be the best way to do this, but I am trying to work with existing scripts as best I can.

Comment: ListOfMembers isn't actually a 'class' here, it's just an Array. What error are you getting? It seems to me you're probably giving the members method the wrong type of collection. Try feeding it a Hash instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `*` to the array name and the method is passed each element as separate argument.

```
members *ListOfMembers
```